# How do I remove old releases from crashlytics?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

We are going through rapid Beta release cycles and piling up releases in Google-Fabric Crashlyitcs. Is there a way to remove old releases from the reporting so we have a clearer picture?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Any admin in your Fabric organization can remove versions from Crashlytics and Beta by heading to your [app’s settings](https://fabric.io/settings/apps). Select the app whose name you want to change and click on the “Versions” button. After that, select the toggle on any build or version you want to disable.

There is not a bulk removal currently or a way to remove the version from Beta while keeping crash reports flowing in.

[Reference from Fabric documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/app.html#remove-versions).